# LibGDX - How do I get my screen to display "LEVEL COMPLETE"?

Tags: android, libgdx, sprite, collision, detection

I want the game screen on the Android device to change to a screen that displays "LEVEL COMPLETE". I made a .png file with this message in the middle and want to basically load it on top of the current screen (like a Fragment i guess?) when **Player** collides with **Flag** (both are modelled as rectangles for the sake of collision detection). This is my Flag class

```
public class Flag extends GameObject {

private Sprite spr;
private Rectangle playerRect;
private boolean isOverlapping;
Player player;
private Rectangle flagRect;

public Flag(Sprite spr, float xPos, float yPos) {
    super(spr, xPos, yPos);
    player = Player.getInstance(null);
    setxPos(xPos);
    setyPos(yPos);
    flagRect = new Rectangle(getxPos(), getyPos(), getSprite().getWidth(),
            getSprite().getHeight());
}

public void update() {

    playerRect = new Rectangle(player.getxPos(), player.getyPos(), player
            .getSprite().getWidth(), player.getSprite().getHeight());
    isOverlapping = playerRect.overlaps(flagRect);
    if(isOverlapping) {
...
}
}
```

}

I put levelComplete.png in my assets folder and am a little unsure where to go from here. Any suggestions? Would be highly appreciated

Comment: i wonder if your problem was solved, if yes could you please turn your question as resolved by choosing correct answer, thank you

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is make a `Texture` from your image and draw it on your screen using `SpriteBatch`. This can be achieved with something like this:

```
public Texture levelComplete = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("assets/imageName.png"));
public SpriteBatch batch = new SpriteBatch();

public render(){
    batch.begin();
    if(isOverlapping){
        batch.draw(levelComplete, x, y);
    }else{
        // render game
    }
    batch.end();
}
```

Note that you might want to put some timer and stop drawing the `Texture` after like 5 seconds or put some sort of "ok" button. Otherwise you will be stuck with the same `Texture`.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating an image that contain your text "Level Complete " you can use BitmapFont to write it down on your screen with any font you like

first choose your font (you can generate any font you want using tools like **Hiero**)
put them on assets file and load them using this line of code

```
textFont = new BitmapFont(Gdx.files.internal("nameFont.fnt"), gdx.files.internal("nameFont.png"), false);
```

then you have just to write your text in the position you want

```
textFont.draw(spritebatch, "Level Complete", x, y)
```

hope it will help !